# Find directories by name without searching matches' subfolders

Tags: linux, command-line, search

How can I search the filesystem only for the first positive match in a path? For example, searching for foo:

```
./some/foo/long/foo/path
./another/foo/long/foo/path
```

should return:

```
./some/foo/
./another/foo/
```

I think the find command should be able to do this, but I can't figure out which flags to use, obviously any other command that achieves the result would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find directories named `foo` and `-prune` them.

```
find . -type d -name foo -prune
```

`find` does not add trailing slashses. If you really need them then:

```
find . -type d -name foo -prune -exec printf '%s/\n' {} +
```

Your `find` may or may not support `-printf` primary. If it does then you can avoid calling an external `printf` executable. E.g. with GNU `find`:

```
find . -type d -name foo -prune -printf '%p/\n'
```

Comment: this is a good answer and I made some edits to the question to clarify the few points it raised

Comment: @maja Answer adjusted. The difference is e.g. in `./some/bar/long/foo/path`, if `./some/foo/` exists. The previous answer would tread `some` as a "directory that contains name", so `some` would be "a match" and "without searching matches' subfolders" would mean we don't want to find `./some/bar/long/foo`. The current answer treats `foo` as "a match" and it finds `./some/bar/long/foo`.